# Can't upgrade php version to 5.4 or higher on ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: php, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I've recently installed Ubuntu server 12.04 on my VPS and after updating the OS I've installed the LAMP stack so that it could run my php application.But the application needs php version to be at least 5.4 but the installed version is 5.3 . I've tried upgrading the php with these set of commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

but after runnig the last one I get this error

> Unpacking apache2-bin (from .../apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb) ...
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
>   dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
>   dpkg-deb: error: subprocess  returned error exit status 2
>   Processing triggers for man-db ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're going to need to remove the old version first. Also, 5.4 is already past end-of-life support. You really should upgrade to 5.6.

Comment: yes ,of course . but first I need to fix this issue , how do you suggest to remove the old version . should I remove the Entire LAMP or only the php?

Comment: Usually, just removing PHP would do it. I see you have an instance of Apache 2.2 installed, as well, though. You may need to update that first; it's also ancient.

Comment: I removed the LAMP packge all together to make it work again

Comment: glad you got it working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to run apt-get -f install on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795304/unable-to-run-apt-get-f-install-on-debian)